# Pass state as arguments to switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement

I have multiple values to show in the component, but only 1 value is to be displayed at a time. So in this case, `valueOne` is true, and I want to use it in a switch statement to return the value. I will create a `div` to show the value.

How do I pass the values from `this.state` as arguments in `switch`?

Is this the proper way to do it? I cannot use ternary operator cause I may have more than 2 values. I will add a call back to close the visible div and will make that value false in this.state and make the one after that true to be listed in the DOM. But how do I do that?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

    const one = () => {
        return(
            <div>
                <p> This is One</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

    class Component extends React.Component{
       state = {
         value: 'one'
    }

    renderSelected = () => {
      switch(this.state.value){
        case 'one' : return <div>{one}</div>
        default : return null
      }
    }

    render(){
      return <div className='main'>{this.renderSelected()}</div>
    }
}

export default MyComp;
```

Here I get a parsing error for `let questOne = {this.state}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the logic inside a function and call it from `render`

```
class Component extends React.Component{
    state = {
        value: 'one'
    }

    renderSelected = () => {
        switch(this.state.value){
            case 'one' : return <div>1</div>
            default : return null
        }
    }

    render(){
        return <div className='main'>{this.renderSelected()}</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I understood the logic here. I added a const outside the class and I want to use it in the return in the switch. But I'm getting a parsed error. I edited the question. Can you please take a look. Many thanks. @Dupocas

Comment: You turned one into a component so you should capitalize the first letter and call It like `<One />` or asign Just the jsx to const one